Keys are messed up and unable to type \ , | and other special characters in gedit in Ubuntu on Windows
I am trying to write programs inside gedit on Unbuntu for Windows but I have encountered a strange issue. After opening gedit when I try to type symbols like | or \ the gedit editor instead recognizes it as a completely different character. The keyboard layout is messed up when I use gedit specifically. Other keys like $, & et cetera seem to work fine. I have Xming installed for gedit. Here are some key mappings as observed when I try to type inside gedit
'@' is getting typed as "
'' is getting typed as '#'
'|' is getting typed as '~'
'#' is getting typed as '£'
I have set my Windows Language to English US and the locale to US inside Ubuntu for Windows. However, gedit seems to be unaffected by anything. Nano and vim work fine but I need to use gedit specifically. Please help. I seriously want to fix this issue.
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS on Windows 10 x86_64 Kernel: 4.4.0-22621-Microsoft
I tried sudo apt full-upgrade
I have set my Windows language to English US and the locale to US inside Ubuntu for Windows.
I tried this but it did not work:
vipulkulshreshtha@VIP-PC-L:~/blabla2$ localectl status Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory vipulkulshreshtha@VIP-PC-L:~/blabla2$ sudo localectl set-keymap us
so I tried:
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
and set the keyboard as Dell (I'm using a Dell laptop) and the keyboard as English US (default)
After that, I did the following:
sudo locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 sudo update-locale LANG=en_US.UTF-8
However, gedit seems to be unaffected by anything. Nano and vim work fine but I need to use gedit specifically. Please help. I read other answers on Stackoverflow and GitHub but nothing helped. I want to fix this issue and continue using gedit on WSL/Ubuntu on Windows. Problem Screenshot

Why are you using an OS that is 6 years out-of-date? Newer versions of Ubuntu likely come with improved gedit.
